# Improving Javascript Mandelbrot Plot Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, fractals, mandelbrot

I have written a javascript program which plots the Mandelbrot set with the normal pretty colours approaching the boundary. I was planning on adding a zoom function next but it is far far too slow for this to be sensible.

I have posted the most important portion of the code here:

```
while (x * x < 2 && y * y < 2 && iteration < max_iteration) {
            xtemp = (x * x) - (y * y) + xcord;
            y = (2 * x * y) + ycord;
            x = xtemp;
            iteration = iteration + 1;
        }
```

and have linked to a jsfiddle with the whole page here: http://jsfiddle.net/728dn2m0/

I have a few global variables which I could take into the main loop but that would result in additional calculations for every single pixel. I read on another SO question that an alternative to the 1x1 rectangle was to use image data but the performance difference was disputed. Another possibility would be rewriting the while statement as some other conditional loop but I'm not convinced that would give me the gains I'm looking for.

I'd consider myself a newbie so I'm happy to hear comments on any aspect of the code but what I'm really after is something which will massively increase performance. I suspect I'm being unreasonable in my expectations of what javascript in the browser can manage but I hope that I'm missing something significant and there are big gains to be found.

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: As there is no specific problem in the strictest sense, the question might be more suitable for code review.

Comment: I'm happy to move it if that would be better. Is it possible to move a question or do I need to create a new question and somehow delete this one?

Comment: My remark was more a suggestion. I checked the jsfiddle and I am a bit surprised on the performance; I noticed that your escape condition is not what is usually done; I think it should be `x*x+y*y<2` instead of `x*x < 2 && y*y<2`.

Comment: I've tried changing the escape condition as you've suggested but there's no change in performance. This from wikipedia: "Because no complex number with a real or imaginary part greater than 2 can be part of the set, a common bailout is to escape when either coefficient exceeds 2." That's why I coded the escape condition as two independent tests. I'm at GMT+7 so am about to go to bed I'll not get to reply again for about another 17 hours. I haven't lost interest!

Comment: @user1977132: "_either coefficient exceeds 2_" is `(x < 2 && y < 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using setInterval as an external loop construct slows the calculation down. You set it to 5 ms for a single pixel, however the entire Mandelbrot map calculation can be done within 1 second. So a single call to your function draws a pixel very quickly and then waits about the 99.99% of that 5 milliseconds.

I replaced

`if (m<=(width+1))`

with

`while (m<=(width+1))`

and removed the setInterval.

This way the entire calculation is done in one step, without refresh to the screen and without using setInterval as an external loop construct. I forked your script and modified it: http://jsfiddle.net/karatedog/2o4gjrv2/6/

In the script I modified the bailout condition from `(x*x < 2 && y*y < 2)` to `(x < 2 && y < 2)` just as I suggested in a previous comment and revealed some hidden pixel, check the difference!

Comment: Have you really modified the bailout condition? Your fiddle still has 'while (x * x < 2 && y * y < 2 && iteration < max_iteration) {'

Comment: Thanks, it must have reverted to the original, but now I fixed it and modified the URL in the answer. You can see the _Mini Mandelbrot_ appearing on this new version.

Comment: Another comment, removing the interval works nicely enough for smaller resolutions but isn't a good option for higher resolutions where the window freezes for several seconds while the calculations take place for the entire set.

Comment: Nice... changing the bailout condition is massively significant. Comparing x^2 was discarding points which should have been in the set. Thank you! I'm still not convinced about removing the interval though! Note though in my answer I had already spotted the problem it was causing and changed it to do one column at a time.

Comment: @user1977132: you are working in a browser with its own limitations, therefor a browser is not the best running environment for creating large Mandelbrot sets. I see no problem waiting for 10-20 seconds to calculate a set just for the sake of testing Javascript, if you go into hardcore areas (like Buddhabrot), you will wait hours - not seconds - to create maps, while you will have to use C language, to squeeze every CPU cycle for a faster finish. Also this computation method is not the most efficient one, not to mention that Mandelbrot calculation can be highly parallelized.

Comment: You don't need to remove the interval. I just pointed out that this solution wastes significant amount of time, it is like adding some `sleep` at the end of every cycle. If you want to keep the setInterval then do some experiment, and increase the amount of pixels that you calculate in one setInterval event (ie.: 2000-5000 pixels). And you iterate 255 times, however the usual iteration at this zoom level (which is: _no zoom_ :-) is around 50, so you can speed up your calculation 5 times just by decreasing the number of iterations. You only need to increase the iterations when you zoom.

Comment: Let's continue the discussion in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61340/discussion-between-karatedog-and-user1977132

Comment: Sorry for not replying, I was out for the evening and am heading to bed now. Thanks for your help, I'll look out for you when I'm next on.

Answer (score 0):

I had indeed missed something significant. The timer I had used in order to prevent the page hanging while the set was plotted was limiting the code to one pixel every 5 milliseconds, in other words 200 pixels per second. Not clever!

I am now plotting one line at a time and it runs a lot better. Not yet real time but it is a lot quicker.

Thanks for the ideas. I will look into the escape condition to see what it should be.

A new jsfiddle with the revised code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/da1qyh9y/

and the for statement I've added is here:

```
function main_loop() {
if (m<=(width+1)) {
    var n;
    for (n=0; n<height; n=n+1) {
```